# cross-chain atomic swaps for ERC721

Tags: erc-20, erc-721

Can cross-chain atomic swaps be implemented for ERC721 too? What are some limitations, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Ethereum side you have no issue. [ERC721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) even implements the function `safeTransferFrom` to pass an extra `data` to a target contract.

```
function safeTransferFrom(address _from,
                          address _to,
                          uint256 _tokenId,
                          bytes data) external payable
```

This allows transfer of tokens to a contract in a single transaction. Replacing `approve` + `transferFrom` of ERC20.